# PHP Image gallery in rows

Tags: php, image, row, gallery

Im working on a image gallery and my upload and delete process does work but now I want to put the images in rows and not under each other which it does now. Here is my output code and I got no clue where to start, can someone show me in the right direction?

To be a little more specific I would like to put 4 images in a row before it "jumps down" and starts a new row. I think I need some kind of loop for this?

```
<?php

include 'includes/db_connect.inc.php';


$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM gallery");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$filename = $row['filename'];
$title = $row['title'];
$id = $row['id'];

    echo '<p>
    <a href="images/'.$filename.'" title="'.$title.'" >
        <img src="images/'.$filename.'" title="'.$title.'" width="300"/>
    </a></p>';

    if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
            echo '<a href="gallery_delete.php?id='.$id.'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you wish to delete the image?\')">Delete Image</a>';

            echo '<hr>';
}

        if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) 
        { 
        ?>
        <p><a href="gallery_form.php?">Add new image</a></p>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simple CSS

```
    echo '<p style="display:inline;">
<a href="images/'.$filename.'" title="'.$title.'" >
    <img src="images/'.$filename.'" title="'.$title.'" width="300"/>
</a></p>';
```

Since `<p>` is a block level tag. They will automatically be placed under each other.

Comment: Yeah, you are right about the <p> tag but still can't get the images in a row.

Comment: @Hubbe I tested the code and its working for me. How about your screen size? try changing width to 100 to test if screen size is the actual problem

Answer (score 0):

Not tested code ..if it doesn't work try yourself with table

```
<?php
     include 'includes/db_connect.inc.php';
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM gallery");
    ?>
    <table>
   <?php
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $filename = $row['filename'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    ?>
       <tr><td>
        <a href="images/'.$filename.'" title="'.$title.'" >
            <img src="images/'.$filename.'" title="'.$title.'" width="300"/>
        </a></td>
    <td>
<?php
        if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
 ?>
<a href="gallery_delete.php?id='.$id.'" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure you wish to delete the image?\')">Delete Image</a>
   </td></tr>
<?php
    }
?>
    </table>
<?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) 
            { 
            ?>
            <p><a href="gallery_form.php?">Add new image</a></p>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Not much progress Im afraid. The images are still under each other and not in rows